# How to have the Center Div stack on top with Bootstrap responsive?

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I'm using Bootstrap 2.3.2 responsive layouts, and trying to have two different orders for a set of Divs. One order for a full screen horizontal layout, and a different one when they are stacked vertically on a smaller screen.

Using a simple setup like this:

```
<div class="row-fluid">
    <div class="span4" id="A">
    </div>
    <div class="span4" id="B">
    </div>
    <div class="span4" id="C">
    </div>
</div>
```

I get A, B, C horizontally on a full sized layout. But on when the screen is shrunk I want to have the vertical stacking be B, A, C.

I've tried this:

```
<div class="row-fluid">
    <div class="span4" id="B">
    </div>
    <div class="span4 pull-left" id="A">
    </div>
    <div class="span4" id="C">
    </div>
</div>
```

But the horizontal layout comes out as B, A, C.

How can I get the horizontal layout of A, B, C and the vertical of B, A, C?

Answer (score 0):

The easiest way is to switch to Bootstrap 3.0.0. There are JS scripts to can re-order elements for you, however Bootstrap's native ways are superior to them, in my opinion.

Check the [**documentation**](http://getbootstrap.com/css/#grid-column-ordering)